# How to save and retrieve NSString value in local directory iPhone?

Tags: iphone, nsstring, local-files

In my iPhone application, there is one options to pick a student name from the UIPickerView. Once the user select one studentname(Maximum 50 name in UIPickerView) from the picker [Eg: Steve]. If the user come back to app after quite the background process and last selected name should be selected in UIPickerView. I solved this by used 'CoreData' but, somebodies do not want to use coredata in app. So, i tried to store the StudentName in local Cache directory and retrieve the student name from there. How can i store the NSString values in Local and update the value when the user update the name and retrieve it to use in app? Please help me to solve this. I dont have experience in Local files. Thanks in advance. If my question not clear please ask me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only need to save 50 items, NSUserDefaults is a fine way to do it. Just save an NSArray.

The file system is totally available to you, you can use all the Posix routines if you want.

Comment: It is perfect guide and answer. Thanks a lot. I fixed the issue.